# Вычислить сумму членов бесконечного ряда C#

Tags: c#, циклы, методы, ряды

Условие задачи:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот мои попытки решения, но цикл for явно задан неправильно:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double x, e, f, chislo = 10, stepen = -5, chisl = x-1, znam1 = x + 1; 

        Console.WriteLine("Введите число X: ");
        x = Double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        e = Math.Pow(chislo, stepen);

        while (f < e)
        {
            for (int n = 1; i < 1000; n++)
            {
                f += Math.Pow(chisl, (2n+1)) / (2n+1) * Math.Pow(znam1, znam);
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine(f);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: Опять? Может Вам почитать какую-нибудь книжку по C#? Как Вы себе представляете последовательность действий - ввод `х` и присвоение `chisl`/`znam1`?  И откуда берется `znam`?

Comment: С удовольствием! Можете что-нибудь посоветовать?

Comment: На данном этапе - любую.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно на каждом шаге вычислять член (Current) и его сравнивать с эпсилон. Если меньше чем эпсилон то выходим из цикла.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double x, e, f, stepen = -5;
        double current;

        Console.WriteLine("Введите число X: ");
        x = Double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        e = Math.Pow(10, stepen);

        for (int n = 1;; n++)
        {
            current = Math.Pow(x-1,2*n+1)/((2*n+1)*Math.Pow(x+1,2*n+1))
            if(current < e) {
                  break;
            }
            f += current;
        }

        Console.WriteLine(f);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: И все? И это *реально* работает?

Comment: не.. я в исходный код не выичтывался )) не подумал что там и с самим вычислением проблемы... сейчас поправлю

Comment: поправил, там да, много ошибок было, извиняюсь что всё не прочёл внимательно

Answer (score 0):

Если есть условие выхода из цикла (eps), и не задано в явном виде количество итераций, то не будет ли логичным использовать цикл

`while (true) {... if (current < eps) break; }?`